# Console based application in C, Need table formatter

Tags: c

I am working with a Ubuntu system on a small project. I have some data tables that are read from SQlite DB. I am not able to print my results in a formatted way, and its killng my productivity. Are there any libs for formatting / beautifying data tables ?

I found a useful one for python (just an example for what I need)
https://code.google.com/p/prettytable/

Is there anything similar for "C" lanuage ?

Comment: Since it's a console application, is there a compelling reason to duplicate the effort that's gone into the python code? Would it make more sense to use the python code in a pipeline instead?

Comment: I wrote a chunk of code to do this in C that I've been meaning to open source. I'm not sure it's suitable for a huge amount of data but I've used it to print tables with around 1000 rows without any noticeable issues. If you're interested I can clean it up and post it on my website this weekend.

Comment: @DaveRager thats encouraging, please post the link once you publish the code.

Comment: `your_program | column -t` :-)

Comment: Ok, it's posted. You can find links to the source files [at this link](http://fourthwoods.com/utils/tableformatter/). I've built this using Cygwin and MinGW. Other platforms might need tweaking. Let me know if you have any problems with it.

Answer (score 2):

You can write your own code for this. It should not be too difficult. The algorithm is like this:

1. Traverse through all the elements for each column and find the element of the longest character length, for every column.
2. Print out the values for the elements of each column (as strings) and append spaces (padding) of the length of (add the difference between the character length of the element and the maximum length value).
3. You may want to add something like " | " between the elements of each column.

You can also try and see if [NCurses](http://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/) can help you as proposed in the referenced StackOverflow page.

Comment: Yes I could. If there is already existing library, I would prefer to use it. Thanks for the algo (y).